# Cluster analysis of time series data with a few points in time

Tags: r, time-series, clustering, multivariate-analysis

I have asked the question here before but have not been able to resolve it.

I have data from 150 participants who were asked about their emotional state at 3 points in time. There are 28 different emotional states, each asked on a 6-point scale of intensity.

My interest is to find out if some clusters can be interpreted in these emotional state change patterns. Could you please tell me a good way to calculate this?
I am using R as my statistical software.

The data is in the following form.

| PP | Time1: Happy | Time2: Happy | Time3: Happy | Time1: Angry | Time2: Angry | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 1 | 2 | ... |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 3 | ... |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 2 | 2 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I am not familiar with methods of clustering.

I could not find a good method of clustering for our data, as most of the explanations of clustering are based on a single dimension or a single sample.

Moreover, I found that most of the clustering methods for time-series data are for data with many more time points, and I do not understand whether it is appropriate to apply them to data with 3 time points.

Thank you.